# WinSCP script fails to transfer file to a remote location

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, winscp, vsftpd

When I try to run a small script using WinSCP client below error throws while transferring the file to the remote server and getting aborted.

Error message

```
C:\WinSCP-5.9.6-Portable>WinSCP.com /script=ftptest.txt
Connecting to 192.169.2.33 ...
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] ftpuser@192.169.2.33
transfer        ascii
\...\audit.log.2018-04-10 |            0 B |    0.0 KB/s | binary |   0%
Error transferring file '\\MainShare\FDS\WS02\Logs\WhvEsbWrk2.MainShare.co.uk\audit.log.2018-04-10'.
Copying files to remote side failed.
Could not create file.
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Abort
```

Script which I have tried

```
open ftp://ftpuser:Mitrai17@192.169.2.33/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 ************************ ftpuser@Filezilla"
ascii
put -transfer=ascii \\MainShare\DFS\WS02\Logs\WhvEsbWrk2.MainShare.co.uk\audit.log.2018-04-10 /home/ftpuser/DK
exit
```

Comment: "Could not create file." You don't have write access to the target directory? Or there is a read-only file already there with the same name?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx  2 ftpuser ftpuser 20480 Apr 11 19:09 DK  @DavidPostill I have permission to that particular directory

Comment: No issues with the FTP server quota. I can confirm that @PimpJuiceIT

Comment: Disk space also fine @PimpJuiceIT  `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       193G  103G   81G  56% /`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `/home/ftpuser/DK` is a directory, you are missing a trailing slash. You should use:

```
put -transfer=ascii \\...\audit.log.2018-04-10 /home/ftpuser/DK/
```

When you use just the `/home/ftpuser/DK`, it means that you want to upload the file to the directory `/home/ftpuser` and save it to the file `DK`. What obviously conflicts with an existing subdirectory of the same name.

Quoting the documentation for the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put):

> The last parameter specifies target remote directory and optionally operation mask to store file(s) under different name. *Target directory must end with slash.*

Comment: Of course, the simple and obvious that's easily overlooked. +1